# no 'object' file generated what is this?

Tags: visual-studio

no 'object' file generated what is this?

I move my c++ code that for QNX, but when I move to VS, I don't know why there is such an error. There is no platform specified code, because I already use Macro to separate them. 
I search on internet this question , no such solution, just tell me to turn it off. I want to know why it happen. The place it happen in two places:

1, try{....
2, srand(time(NULL)), even I remove this line, still throw out error.

Comment: Could you please be a pit more specific?

Comment: Voting to close unless the OP fixes his question.

Comment: 99.9% of the time when your question and subject are identical, you didn't put enough effort into the question.

Answer (score 8):

A lot more information is needed before the underlying problem can be solved, but here's my best guess as to what your current situation is:

It's probable that you have one or more warnings during compilation and the "warnings treated like errors" option (`/WX`) is on, or you have one or more actual errors. Either way, the compiler therefore is not generating the object file or executable.